# Multiple php-fpm containers behind nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx, matomo, nextcloud

I want to "dockerize" three php based web apps behind nginx as proxy/frontend (also docker, [official container](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)): own app, piwik ([official php-fpm docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/piwik/)) and nextcloud ([official php-fpm docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud/))

It works fine with one php-fpm container but not with two or more (/var/www/html is used in at least two php-fpm containers: nextcloud, piwik). The db container is omitted for simplification.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
    nextcloud_data:

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:stable
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
    volumes_from:
      - nextcloud
      - piwik # (a)
    links:
      - nextcloud
      - piwik # (a)
    restart: always
  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud:11.0-fpm
    volumes:
      - nextcloud_data:/var/www/html
    restart: always
  piwik:
    image: piwik:fpm
    restart: always
```

nginx-Config `conf.d/piwik.conf` - inspired by [Indiehosters](https://github.com/indiehosters/piwik/blob/master/nginx.conf):

```
upstream php-piwik {
    server piwik:9000;
}

server {
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name piwik.example.org;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass php-piwik;
    }
}
```

Config for nextcloud is similar (nextcloud.example.org).

Piwik works fine with this setting (nextcloud is broken, `/var/www/html` in web container contains piwik stuff). When i comment out the (a) marked lines and disable piwik.conf nextcloud works fine but piwik is broken (`/var/www/html` contains nextcloud stuff). My problem is that they share the same path (`/var/www/html`). How can i avoid this with official images?